# Postfix + Unbound for a Single IP Address Only

Tags: postfix, unbound

I'm running in to an issue using zen.spamhaus.org in Postfix. It appears too many people are using the same nameservers I am using .. and I'm getting blocked.

What I'd like to do is setup Postfix to use Unbound (in recursive mode). I believe that's what I need to do in order to get zen.spamhaus.org working correctly.

The issue I am having is this :

In the unbound.conf file, what do I need to use for "interface" and "access-control" in the server block? I only want to allow the postfix public IP address of 11.22.33.44 access.

So do I use that IP address for both entries? I just can't seem to find any straight-forward documentation on this.

Once my unbound.conf file is setup, how to I get Postfix to use it? If I modify my resolv.conf and update the nameservers, that will effect all IP's on my box. So I'm confused how this will exactly work.

Any assistance on this would be greatly appreciated. For something that should be dead simple to setup, it's sure confusing as hell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want unbound to listen on localhost only 127.0.0.1;

Tell it to lookup DNS directly

```
root-hints: "/etc/unbound/root.hints"
```

then check that it's working with a simple

```
nslookup Google.com 127.0.0.1
```

And then point resolve to 127.0.0.1.

[Unbound documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unbound#Root_hints)